# $f: R \rightarrow R$ be a function such that $f(2-x)=f(2+x)$ and $f(4-x)=f(4+x)$ ,for all $x \in R$ , then $f(x)$ is a periodic function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

If $f: R \rightarrow R$ be a function such that $f(2-x)=f(2+x)$ and $f(4-x)=f(4+x)$ ,for all $x \in R$ and $\int_0^2 f(x)dx=5$. Then the value of $\int_{10}^{50} f(x)dx$ =?

Can anyone please tell me how to mathematically prove that the function $f(x)$ is a periodic function on $\Bbb{R}$.

If I can prove that, I will be done.

Comment: Interesting question.. What haveytou tried??

Comment: I can visualize that the function is periodic with period $2$.

Comment: Visualizing is good and necessary.. Do you want to share your visualization?

Comment: A little cheating: for the second question to be answerable, $2$ must be a half-period and the requested integral is $20$ times longer.

Answer (score 3):

Let $2-x=t$, then $f(t)=f(4-t)$. But $f(4-t)=f(4+t)$. So $f(t)=f(4+t)$. Thus $f$ is periodic.

This means, 
$$f(5+x)=f(1+x).$$
Moreover,
\begin{align*}
f(5+x)& =f(2+(3+x))\\
&=f(2-(3+x))\\
&=f(-1-x)
\end{align*}
Thus
$$f(1+x)=f(-(1+x)).$$
This means $f$ is an even function.

Answer (score 1):

The first identity means geometrically that the function is mirrored by the axis $x=2$. And it is also mirrored by $x=4$, hence this repeats periodically.

Answer (score 0):

as it was shown by the 2 answers the given function has a period $T=4$. Also $f$ in the intervals $[0,4], [4,8]..$ is mirrowed by the lines $x=2, x=6,...$ .

So $\int_0^4f=\int_0^2f+\int_2^4f=2\int_0^2f=10$

At last $\int_{10}^{50}f=\int_{12}^{52}f+\int_{10}^{12}f-\int_{50}^{52}f=10 \cdot10=100$